# How can i read CloudQueueMessage.DequeueCount from a Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-storage-queues

I have a Logic App that reads messages from an Azure Storage Queue.
If the logic app fails the message is put back on the queue.
I'd like to be able to read the CloudQueueMessage.DequeueCount in my logic app but that property does not seem to be exposed to my logic app.

It's simple to read that property in an Azure Function - but in this case I'm using a logic app.

Is there a way to read the CloudQueueMessage.DequeueCount property in a Logic App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `DequeueCount` is a property of a message, when you get a message from the queue you will get all properties.

You could get `DequeueCount` directly with `Get Messages` action from the **OUTPUTS**.

[image]

Or you could choose to get the value with **Compose** Action. After **Get Messages** action, add a **Compose** action,in the input box paste the following **Expression**:

```
body('Get_messages')?['QueueMessagesList']?['QueueMessage']?[0]?['DequeueCount']
```

And it will get the same value as the Outputs.

[image]

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions,please let me know.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason Get Messages where empty when I added the Compose construct? But I was able to do a Compose after "When there are messages in a queue". After that it was easy to do a Parse JSON (I use the JSON later on for other purposes as well) to read the DequeueCount property.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Logic apps doesn't have a connector with Azure queues, more on the [**Documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/apis-list) . However, there is a connector that is specific to Azure Service Bus, which is also one of the Queue products offered by Azure.

Comment: Hi! Strange that they were not listed? It works very well to do "Add Action" and choose Azure Queues. Works well both to read and write from a Logic App.

Comment: That's true, I'll sync up with the product team to have them add it to the document :)